# Getting wrong output from sscanf using %d

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse(char *line, int x, int y){
    sscanf(line,"%d %d", &x, &y);
}

int main(){
    int x;
    int y;
    char *line = "2 3";
    parse(line,x,y);
    printf("exponent = %d and number = %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get the correct values to have `x=2` and `y=3` but when I run I get `x = -1659548064` and `y = 32765`.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: C is *pass by value*. If you pass `x` and `y` in  `void parse(char *line, int x, int y)` then the function receives a *copy of* `x` and `y` and any changes made in the function are lost when the function returns. To avoid this, pass a pointer, the function will receive a *copy of* the pointer, but the copy will hold the same address as its value as the original did in `main()`. (and it follows the change the address of a pointer in a function you have to pass the *address of* the pointer from the caller)

Answer (score 2):

In C, parameters passed *by value*, like `x` and `y` in

```
void parse(char *line, int x, int y){
    sscanf(line,"%d %d", &x, &y);
}
```

are copies of the variables used by the caller as parameters. So, any assignment performed on them will have no effect outside the function. Why do you see those strange values? Well, since `parse` doesn't affect `x` and `y`, they will maintain their previous values. But since you didn't initialize them they will have a random value depending on what was previously stored in their memory locations.

Whenever a parameter is an output of a function (and for some reason cannot be returned) it can be passed as a **pointer**: the address of a variable is passed, so that the output can be stored there.

In this case:

```
void parse(char *line, int *x, int *y){
    sscanf(line,"%d %d", x, y);
}
```

and `main` becomes

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int y;
    char *line = "2 3";
    parse(line, &x ,&y);  // <--- changes here!!!
    printf("exponent = %d and number = %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

So:

- *addresses* of the original local variables are passed.
- this can be done because I changed `parse()` interface in order to accept *pointers* to integer
- within `parse`, since `scanf` expects a pointer to integer for each `%d`, I can pass simply `x` and `y` instead of `&x` and `&y` like in your version

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass x and y as pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse(char *line, int *x, int *y){
    sscanf(line,"%d %d", x, y);
}

int main(){
    int x;
    int y;
    char *line = "2 3";
    parse(line,&x,&y);
    printf("exponent = %d and number = %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer provides a solution, but no explanation. Why does OP need to pass pointers to `parse()`?